# Control calls on physical phone from PC software

Tags: windows-10, phone

Looking for a solution to place calls programmatically from a Windows PC to a connected physical phone.

Final result should be that pressing something in the PC should place a call on a connected physical phone. Not calling with VOIP and also not using the PC audio and mic for the phone call. I need just to send a command from the PC that will place the call without the need to dial the number manually.

This is for a company that calls hundreds of numbers every day for delivery proposes.

Comment: Windows / Linux / Mac ?

Comment: I use Windows 10

Comment: You would need a product, but product-asking questions are off-subject on our site.

Comment: An old (second hand) telephone modem can be used as a dialer. Just like you can have multiple telephones/ handsets on line at the same time, you can have the dialer online to do the dialing for you. If you can set that up, come back and ask "How to dial using modem".  (Incidentally, as you can see from this comment, there was nothing wrong with your question: it didn't need an opinion based product, material or service recommendation, and the answer won't go out of date.) People just close questions they don't know the answer to, which would be fair enough if they were the only ones answering.